# Contentful use Cloudinary images within Rich text for blog post

Tags: cloudinary, contentful

I have a blog built with NextJs, and I currently use a Rich Text type for my blog post, which at the moment uses the default 'Insert Media' option within Contentful, however I would like to switch this up to Cloudinary.
I have followed the [Contentful guide](https://www.contentful.com/help/cloudinary-app/) but that does not allow me to use the images within the Rich Text, they are just their own field within the Content Model.

Is there a way I can upload these images to Cloudinary and then use them within my Rich text, in a similar way to 'Insert media'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contentful DevRel here

I would suggest creating a separate content type, such as `cloudinaryAsset` where you have a field for your Cloudinary image URL, title, description etc.

You can insert this as a linked entry in your Rich Text field and do what you need with the `cloudinaryAsset` content type in your Rich Text Renderer on the front end.

Comment: Hello   
I have created my content type, included and image, title and then the description. But I can't spot how to add the linked entry. I have just realised that I am actually using 'Long text' rather than 'Rich Text'.  
Would I need to change this over to Rich Text to be able to do that?

Comment: Yes that's right, you can't use linked entries in long text/markdown. You'll need to switch the field type to Rich Text. (You'll need to create a new field rather than switching the type though.)